# Dynamic table with ionic

Tags: html, typescript

Hello I working on an app and I have this html code where I'll display some data I get from API:

```
<ion-content>
    <p style="color: red;"> 
      <ion-card>

        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title> Title </ion-card-title>
          <ion-card-subtitle> Start </ion-card-subtitle>
        </ion-card-header>

        <ion-card-content>
          some description
        </ion-card-content>

      </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

And I have this model:

```
let short_intervents = [
      {
        "title": "08:00 382 COMPANY NAME",
                "description": "Hour: 08:00:00 09:00:00",
                "start": "2014-03-31",
                "id": 1,
                "resourceId": "2",
                "color": "#63e791"
      },
      {
        "title": "08:00 382 COMPANY NAME",
                "description": "Hour: 08:00:00 09:00:00",
                "start": "2015-03-31",
                "id": 2,
                "resourceId": "2",
                "color": "#63e791"
      },
      {
        "title": "08:00 382 COMPANY NAME",
                "description": "Hour: 08:00:00 09:00:00",
                "start": "2016-03-31",
                "id": 3,
                "resourceId": "2",
                "color": "#63e791"
      }
    ]
```

How can I create my html dynamically given these information?
Thank you

Comment: Was just about to post this in your other question, hope it helps. ->  `\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
<ion-card *ngFor = "let data of short_intervents" [ngStyle] = "{'border-right': '10px solid' + data.color}">

    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Title: {{data.title}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>Start: {{data.start}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
      Description: {{data.description}}
    </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use div with *ngFor to show the cards like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of short_intervents>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title> Title </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle> Start </ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      some description
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

Another possibility is to use ion-list with ngFor too like this:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data of short_intervents>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title> Title </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle> Start </ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      some description
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```